# When will nodejs support es6 style module(import/export)?

Tags: module, ecmascript-6

I did a quick search, but failed to find the answer. Does anyone knows?

Comment: Are you actually asking when node supports es6 modules? Because I fail to see how this would be relevant for npm. Could you be more specific? In a sense, npm doesn't support any module system, it doesn't care what the source files are written in.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, and I have changed the question

Comment: Current status is reflected in this document: https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/blob/master/002-es6-modules.md

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following terminal command in unix-based OSs:

```
node <file-name.extension> --v8-options | grep harmony
```

,or you can do the same on Windows platform like the following:

```
node <file-name.extension> --v8-options | findstr harmony
```